# Using Brown corpus for text classification NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am trying to use brown corpus genres as a task of classification but I am obtaining very low accuracy scores. I trying different features for examples the frequency of stopwords. Could you check if I am doing it right or is there a problem with my code? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import brown,stopwords
import random
import nltk

dataset = [] # 500 samples

for category in brown.categories():
    for fileid in brown.fileids(category):
        dataset.append((brown.words(fileids = fileid),category))

dataset = [([w.lower() for w in text],category) for text,category in dataset]

def feature_extractor(text,bag):
    # bag -> bag of words
    frec = defaultdict(int)
    for word in text:
        if word in bag:
            frec[word] += 1

    return frec

# training & test 90%-10% naivebayes nltk

def train_and_test(featureset,n=90):

    random.shuffle(featureset)
    split = int((len(featureset)*n)/100)
    train,test = featureset[:split],featureset[split:]
    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train)
    accuracy= nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test)
    return accuracy

# Stopwords as features
stopwords = stopwords.words("english") # 153 words

featureset = [(feature_extractor(text,stopwords),category)for text,category in dataset]

print("Accuracy: ",train_and_test(featureset)) # around 0.25
```

Comment: You should be using content words as features, not stopwords...-_-||| Stopwords = non-informative words like "the", "a", "it", "she", etc.

Comment: I think changing `if word in bag:` -> `if word not in bag:` should get you the numbers you hope for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have tried it and I get even lower scores. I am getting now 0.02

Comment: Impossible....? I'll try it for myself after work today ;P

Comment: Thanks :) there must be something wrong. I just can't figure out what it is